# Loading Docker container in PyCharm

Tags: macos, docker, pycharm

I started taking the Udacity Deep Learning course and I came across the first assignment. They have provided a bunch of IPython notebooks and a docker file. [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity) is the link. How do I load this in PyCharm? I have downloaded and installed [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/#/docker-for-mac) and I have installed the [Docker Integration plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7724) for PyCharm. I am unable to figure out how to load the Docker file in PyCharm as given in the instructions.

Comment: Instructions are pretty clear, Did you execute `docker run` command?

Comment: @Farhad Yes. Once I do that, I am able to load the notebooks in my browser by going to http://127.0.0.1:8888 . How do I get them to load in PyCharm?